# Cannot add data into database in visual c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

As a beginner to c#, and I actaully spent a lot of time researching this:
I cannot add some data into the database, I can extract data from it, but cannot add anything into the database. I use sql server as my database.

```
try {    
    fname = fname_tb.Text;// first name
    sname = sname_tb.Text; // second name
    q = "insert into beforebath1(firstname,secondname) values(@fname,@sname)";
    conn_string = Properties.Settings.Default.beforebath_connection_string;
    SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(conn_string);
    SqlCommand cmd;

    co.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(q, co);
    cmd.Connection = co;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname_tb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", sname_tb.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    co.Close();  
}
catch(Exception err) {
    MessageBox.Show(err.toString());   
}
```

my sql connection string is this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\beforebath_db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

It is automatically generated when I created the database. Please help me insert the text in the two textboxes (`fname_tb.Text` and `sname_tb.Text`) into the table called `beforebath1` of the database called `beforebath_db.mdf`.

Is it something to do with my data directory?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or messages?

Comment: Exactly what happens. It is never helpful to say "it doesn't work".

Comment: Attach your database to a real instance of SQL Server. Stop using this AttachDbFileName syntax; it means that your app, Management Studio, and Visual Studio all have a separate copy of the database file!

Comment: `Insert into table_name`, sounds like table_name should really say `beforebath1`? Otherwise, please provide more information on what is going wrong per @drneel's comment.

Comment: Are you remembering to enclose your strings with apostrophes?  It doesn't look like it from what I see here... unless you're adding them into the textboxes manually.

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting, if it is not the lack of single quotes it might be a permissions issue.

Comment: There isnt any error, even after inserting the data, the database is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of mistakes in your code.

**First, why catch an exception that will only be shown in a message?**

It is often best to let the exception bubble up to have the stack trace in debug. This is not the same if this is production code, which I doubt.

**Second, make sure to dispose your objects adequately.**

The [**Using Statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx) is the most prefered way to work with disposeable items such as a database connection and a command.

```
using (var cnx = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    cnx.Open();

    var sql = @"insert into beforebath1 (first_name, second_name)
                values (@fname, @lname)";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnx)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname_tb.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname_tb.Text);

        try {
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (0 < rowsAffected) MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            else MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
        } catch (SqlException ex) {
            // It is almost prefered to let the exception be thrown freely
            // so that you may have its full stack trace and have more 
            // details on your error.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } finally {
            if (cnx.State == ConnectionState.Open) cnx.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, wrapping your disposable objects within `using` blocks, you make sure that everything is getting to get disposed automatically when exiting the code block.

As for your "it doesn't work" problem, I guess the problem be either at the connection string level, or at your `table_name` level.

You wish to insert into `beforebath1`, and your insert statement states `table_name`. Make sure you put the right table name where it belongs so that it may work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i changed my code as per this, after executing, the message box showed 'success'. but the data is not yet inserted into my table.

Comment: Perhaps shall you give `select @@trancount` a try to see if there are any uncommited transaction so that your command shall return the number of rows properly, except that your SQL Server instance might be configured to process transactions which would cause your inserted row to never appear into your table. Otherwise, make sure to put a breakpoint on your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line so that you may quickwatch how your `insert` statement is built. Then you shall see whether the proper values are passed to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change you connection string to this:

```
Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Database=beforebath_db;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

This means the your app and other programs using the Db will all share the same instance.

Also, as mentioned by @Will, you should wrap your SQLConnection in a using statement for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

For better implementations  you can use stored_procedures like bellow:

Step1: Declare Stored Procedure for your Query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_TO_BEFORE_PATH_SP]
    /*Type of this variables should be their column types*/
    @fname varchar(MAX),
    @lname varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[beforebath1] (fname, lname)
           VALUES (@fname,@lname)
END
```

Step2: Using Stored Procedure where you need:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("ADD_TO_BEFORE_PATH_SP", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname_tb.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname_tb.Text);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
try
{
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Close();
}
```